# Mirror desktop items on two monitors

Tags: display, desktop, dual-screen

I don't want to mirror my monitors but I would like the files in ~/Desktop to display on both. Right now they only display on my primary monitor. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make items appear twice on what is essentially the same desktop, but you can view the contents of your desktop as a folder.

The simplest method using default settings is to open a new folder in Finder,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>  , then Desktop should be one of the Favourites on the Sidebar.